# Trying to remove up to 2 digits following a match

Tags: java, regex

Say I have a few string like `Foo3,5bar`, `Foo14,5bar` and `Foo23,42bar`

I want to remove the second number, following the comma, as well as the comma, using Java Regex.

So far, I've tried `String.replaceAll("(?<=Foo\d{1,2}),\d{1,2}", "")`, using `(?<=Foo\d{1,2}),\d{1,2}` as my regex, but it's not working.

Comment: Ok, allow me to explain the purpose of this. I'm parsing IRC Color codes, and I need to remove the background character. `Foo` is just a standin for `\x03` or the ETX character. There is text beyond it, and there ma be more than one. For example, "Foo3,4HelloFoo5,3World" should become "Foo3HelloFoo5World" I apologize for not making this more clear, but there you go.

Comment: I've come up with `(?<=Foo\d\d|\d),(\d\d?|\d)`, but the problem with that is that it'll match any 1-2 digit number with a trailing comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`String#replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) that has regex support:

```
String str = "Foo3,4HelloFoo5,3World";
str = str.replaceAll("(\\d),\\d+", "$1"); // Foo3HelloFoo5World
```

OR else if you want to restrict matching to max 2 digits after comma then use:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(\\d),\\d{1,2}", "$1"); // Foo3HelloFoo5World
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/5P1guJ

Comment: This doesn't work if there's a number after the code, or with things with a comma after, like
`"Foo3,4HelloFoo5,3World,45"`

http://ideone.com/dKwb2O

Comment: @ron975 For this string this will give `Foo3HelloFoo5World`. What other output do you expect?

Comment: Foo3HelloFoo5World,45.

I'm parsing [IRC Color codes](http://www.mirc.com/colors.html), I just want to remove the background code. `Foo` is a stand-in for ASCII `\x03` or `^C` in Caret notation

Comment: It's close, but it breaks if the input after the code is a number, or a number followed by trailing comma. If someone were to type something like `,50HelloWorld,453Bar,34,1Hello`, with colors making that string `Foo03,04,50HelloFoo5,3World,45Foo4,123Bar,34Foo34,34,1Hello` again, `Foo` representing the ASCII ETX character, it'll break. I don't know why anyone would type that in an IRC channel, but it should be able to parse that regardless. Expected Output is `Foo03,50HelloFoo5World,45Foo43Bar,34,1Hello`http://ideone.com/YJspC0

Comment: @ron975: What should be output for input: `Foo03,04,50HelloFoo5,3World,45Foo4,123Bar,34Foo34,34,1Hello` ?

Comment: `Foo03,50HelloFoo5World,45Foo43Bar,34Foo34,1Hello`

Comment: Oh ok, got it. You don't want to replace `,\d+` following that. Let me rework and revert back.

Comment: @ron975 Try the regex from my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16093716/637284). It reproduces your intended output. https://ideone.com/W7IuT1

Comment: @ron975: Edited, you can try it now or see this demo: **http://ideone.com/2DYguI**

Comment: @anubhava Not exactly the desired output: Notice the part `45Foo4Bar` instead of correct `45Foo43Bar`

Comment: @halex: Well ofcourse If I use: `str.replaceAll("(\\d),\\d{1,2}", "$1")` it will **completely match** OP's output but I'm not sure if he needed to  match max 2 digit numbers only after comma.

Comment: This seems to work fine, I used the one for matching max 2 digits as IRC codes are only maximum 2 digits long. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = str.replaceFirst(",\\d+$")
```

Comment: Based on the updates to the question, we shouldn't need that `$` in the regex anymore.

Answer (score 0):

what about Integer.valueOf(str.substring(string.lastIndexOf(",")+1));
is regex a necessity ?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is almost correct. You forget to escape the `\` in the regex. The correct one is:

```
(?<=Foo\\d{1,2}),\\d{1,2}
```

Note the `\\` instead of `\`.

See https://ideone.com/W7IuT1 for a demo on your strings.